# why the curvature of a spiral in its origin is not infinity?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

It can be shown that the curvature of a spiral $\bf{r}(\rm t)=t(\cos t, \sin t)$ is given by

\begin{eqnarray}
    \kappa(t) = \frac{t^2 + 2}{(\sqrt{1+ t^2})^3}
\end{eqnarray}

Given that the radius at $t=0$ is $0$, I would think that the curvature is
infinity. Still $\lim_{t \to 0} \kappa(t) = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that you're confusing polar radius with radius of curvature.

The polar radius is $0,$ but the radius of curvature isn't. The curve doesn't knot into a point at the origin. Also, from a plot of the curve, the osculating circle is far from being degenerate. Thus, the radius of curvature is positive and finite.

Comment: You are right. Polar radius and radius of curvature are not the same thing.  Still, I see a spiral as curving into a "circle" of radius 0. That is just my intuition.  However, I confused. First, I thought that $t( \cos t, \sin t)$ was an spiral but the graph shows different. But then if I write this in polar coordinates I find that $r = t$, $\theta=t$ and $r=\theta$ is an spiral right?

Comment: If I use the equation in polar coordinates  $\kappa=\frac{r^2 \theta'^3 + 2 r'^2 \theta' - r r'' \theta' + r r'\theta''}{(r'^2 + r^2 \theta'^2)^{3/2} } $ (for r(t)=t, $\theta(t)=$.  I see that $\kappa=\frac{t^2+2}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}$ that has as limit as $t \to 0$, $\kappa(0)=2$.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo Yes, the curve defined in OP is not a spiral. I'd been bothered that you called it a spiral. But since you had an equation that unambiguously defined what you meant, I didn't bother anymore. If it's a spiral that curls into the origin, then you're right that the curvature should approach infinity.

Comment: I disagree $r=\theta$ is a spiral an in zero the curvature is 2. That is what I posted above. In polar coordinates $r(t)=\theta(t)=t$ is a spiral. Now, how do you write $t( \cos t, \sin t)$ in polar coordinates?

Comment: @HermanJaramillo The archimedean spiral does not curl into the origin fast enough. I was talking intuitively. But to emphasise what I said in my answer, the polar radius $r(\theta)$ is completely different from the radius of curvature. I think this is what might have caused the confusion for you. That a curve enters into the origin (that is, $r$ vanishes) does not guarantee that it is infinitely curved there, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I finally answered my question with the help of WolframAlpha.

After a few tests here is what we have.
We have a user who removed his name from this blog, so I do not have who to give credits to. He suggested that the figure was not a spiral and plotted something like:

[[image: spiral for <span class=]$t$ between -5, 5 ">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckGpd.png)

To get the picture in your browser just click
[first figure](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parameteric%20plot%20%20(%20t%20(%20cos%20%20t,%20%20sin%20t),%20t%3D-5,5)))

It seems as if the picture is not a spiral but it is. 
See what happens when we pick $t \in [0, 20]$.
[image: spiral for $t \in [0, 20]

You can load this figure in your browser by clicking
[here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parameteric%20plot%20%20(%20t%20(%20cos%20%20t,%20%20sin%20t),%20t%3D0,20)))

Now to understand what is going on let us choose $t \in [-1,10]$.
Here is the figure.

[image: spiral with $t \in [-1,10]]

You can load the picture in your browser by clicking
[here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parameteric%20plot%20%20(%20t%20(%20cos%20%20t,%20%20sin%20t),%20t%3D-1,10)))

It is now clear that for $t=0$ you can make a small circle with radius
$1/2$, center at $[0,1/2]$ tangential at the $x$ axis at $(0,0)$. 
The curvature of this circle is $\kappa=2$. The figure does not lie
but my intuition was wrong and I thought that this spiral collapse 
to a point $(0,0)$ while indeed it just passes through that point
tangentially.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some insights as to why the curve has the behaviour it has.

### Symmetry around zero

The first thing to notice is that $t,\sin t$ are odd functions whereas $\cos t$ is even. Hence $t\cos t$ is odd and $t\sin t$ is even. This implies that the curve of the form $\mathbf r(t)=(odd,even)$ must be symmetrical around the $y$-axis. Due to this symmetry, the center of curvature for $t=0$ must lie on the $y$-axis. Let $(0,y)$ be the center of a circle through $(0,0)$ and $\mathbf r(t)$. Then we have:
$$
y^2=t^2\cos^2 t+(y-t\sin t)^2\\
\Updownarrow\\
y=\frac t{2\sin t}
$$
This clearly tends to $y=1/2$ as $t$ tends to zero. Thus we have placed the center of curvature for $t=0$ at $(0,y)=(0,1/2)$ which verifies $\kappa(0)=2$.

### Resemblance to a parabola

First some useful facts to note:

- Tangents are first order differential approximations.
- Circles of curvature coincide locally with second order differential approximations.

Now what happens near $t=0$? We have the first order approximations $\cos t\approx 1$ and $\sin t\approx t$ which allows us to derive the second order approximations:
$$
\mathbf r(t)=t(\cos t,\sin t)\approx t(1,t)=(t,t^2)
$$
and so the graph of $\mathbf r(t)$ resembles the graph of the quadratic function $f(t)=t^2$ near $t=0$.

### General second order approximations

More generally, one can show that we have the second order approximation:
$$
\mathbf r(t)\approx t \mathbf e_1+t(t-t_0)\mathbf e_2
$$
near $t=t_0$ where $\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2$ are the perpendicular unit vectors:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf e_1&=(\cos t_0,\sin t_0)\\
\mathbf e_2&=(-\sin t_0,\cos t_0)
\end{align}
$$
In fact we have the parabola $f(t)=t(t-t_0)$ in the coordinate system defined by the basis $\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2$. This has zeros for $t=0$ and $t=t_0$ corresponding to the origin $(0,0)$ and the point $\mathbf r(t_0)$ on the curve. Only for $t_0=0$ we have a double root so that this parabola has its vertex at the curve point.